# htaccess to nginx simple url rewrite conversion

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying to rewrite the following .htaccess to nginx for last 2 hours, first tried all the online converters and no luck, also tried looking at examples of conversion but haven't found this conversion anywhere: `^system.*`

If anyone could help me I would highly appreciate.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried - it might just require a minor fix? `^system.*` (the same as `^system`) is just a simple regular expression and is probably the same in nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache assumes a leading forward slash. Nginx does not.

```
location ~* "^/system.*" {
    try_files $uri /index.php$uri;
}
```

Also, don't use those online converters. There are better ways of handling file existence in Nginx that they don't take into account. Check this out:

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Check_IF_File_Exists